# Hide records count from ActiveAdmin scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

Active Admin lets you define scopes this way :

```
scope :all
scope :opened
scope :closed
```

The problem is that it will also display the total record count next to each scope on the index page. This COUNT query can slow down page load a lot when millions of records are involved. ActiveAdmin already lets you hide the total count for the index page this way :

```
index :pagination_total => false
```

Is there something similar for scopes? If so, I can't find it!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In v0.4.2, a commit was introduced adding a `show_count` option to `scope`:
[[c12dc45] Adds ability to suppress scope count on a per-scope basis](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/commit/c12dc45cdb1922e131044f75bbdcace0213518db).

The included test (yay testing!) describes this well:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  scope :all, default: true, show_count: false
end
```

I'm not sure how the feature is documented; you might want to propose changes in that regard.

Comment: Is there a way to make this toggle-able? Like `show_count: params[:show_count]`, I can't add `params` in this section right?